# Laravel Group by Custom date Field

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, date

I have have more than 16,000 data with corresponding date. I put these date in 'date' field in my table.  I want to show these data group by months, I tried but I failed, my date format: `date: "2015-08-31 02:12 "`

My query:

```
$data = \App\Crawler::select([
        \DB::raw('count(id) as `count`'), 
        \DB::raw('Month(date) as month')
    ])->groupBy('month')->get();
```

I want:

```
{
  { 
    month: july
    count: 100
  },
  { 
    month: march
    count: 100
  }
}
```

Comment: Rewrite the question. What was the expectations? What did work?  What didn't work?  Give sample data and show it differs from the result that you wanted.

Comment: Work smarter, not harder.  There is no reason for you to not use a datetime field...

Comment: @Devon, I carwled data from a newsapaper , so that i store this data in 'date' field

Comment: @AbuTalha...all you had to do was add `:00` (seconds) and it would have fit in a datetime then date functions through MySQL would work...

Comment: "2015-08-31 02:12 " is not a date.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to get the month name using MySQL's `MONTHNAME()` function.

This should work even if you don't have a full timestamp stored.

```
$data = \App\Crawler::select([
    \DB::raw('count(id) as `count`'), 
    \DB::raw('monthname(date) as month')
])->groupBy('month')->get();
```

```
[
    {
        count: 3,
        month: "July"
    },
    {
        count: 1,
        month: "March"
    }
]
```

Comment: it returns ` [
 {
count: 16749,
month: null
}
]`